# How do I go about testing my own code when using OROPlatform?

Tags: php, symfony, orocrm, orocommerce

I have started a brand new application using just raw OROPlatform. I have wrote some code (entities and configs etc.) I however cannot find in the documentation how and where to place unit and integration tests that would just test my code, not the ORO engine code.

When I run `vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit` from the root directory I get the following:

```
ERRORS!
Tests: 33889, Assertions: 91151, Errors: 2227, Failures: 894, Warnings: 9, Skipped: 443, Incomplete: 4.
```

So it looks like this is testing the whole giant ORO engine code, however I just want to run my own tests that test my own code. How do I go about directory structure and config?

Answer (score 1):

Michał, how about use `--filter` option with phpunit? e.g.

```
phpunit -- fileter=ClassNameOrMethodName
```

Or you can even pass your test folder as an argument to phpunit:

```
phpunit path/to/you/test/folder
```